# Communication between Raspberry and ESP32

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

At the moment I work at a school project and the goal is at the moment, that an ultrasonic sensor of an ESP can communicate with a Raspberry pi 3B+. So the goal is when the Sensor detects an object,  it should give the Raspberry a signal.

When the Raspberry got the signal he makes a photo and saves it locally on the raspberry.

First I tried that the Raspberry saves each image at a different name. It works after I ask in this group for help. Secondly, I tried to use GPIO as the communication between the ESP and the Raspberry. Of course, my code of the ESP is already finished but the communication between them doesn't work.

```py
import time
import os                                                                                       
from picamera import PiCamera                                                                   
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)                                                                          

GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN)                                                                         

if __name__=='__main__':
    while True:
        if(GPIO.input(18) == GPIO.HIGH):



            cam = PiCamera()


            os.chdir('/home/pi/Desktop/image/')                                                  
            images = [i for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if i.lower().startswith('image')]       



            if images:
                newest = max(images, key=os.path.getmtime)                                      

            else:
                newest = 'image0.jpg'


            number = int(''.join([i for i in newest if i.isdigit()]))                           
            newimagen = 'image'+str(number+1)+'.jpg'                                            

            cam.resolution = (2592,1944)                                                        

            cam.capture('/home/pi/Desktop/image/'+newimagen)
```

```
#define trigPin 12
#define echoPin 13
#define ledPin  14


long duration;
int distance;

boolean triggered = false;

double activateDistance = 10;

void setup() {
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); 
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600); 

}

void loop() 
{

  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);


digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(5);
digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);




  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);


  distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;


  if (distance <= activateDistance)
  {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    delay(500);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }

}
```

As I say, I expect that when the Sensor detects an Object, the Raspberry makes a photo. 
I think it would be important, that I say, that the esp gives a signal with the help of a cable that I connect on a pin of the Esp and a pin of the Raspberry.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any code on the ESP that would signal the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: and the if(distance <=  activateDistance) should be a part of the code that give a signal, doesn't it? The code that is in comment should give a signal wait and when the sensor detects an object should resend a signal. The other one should give one signal and then should not resend a signal

Comment: I can see a commented out write to an LED. Surely you need an actual write to the pin corresponding to Raspi pin 18?

Comment: Ok. The commented out write as you said is a code that a friend propose me and said that I also can use it for the Raspberry. I also add a sentence on my "article" there you can see that I want that the signal should be send by a pin on thr Esp to an other pin of the Raspberry with a cable.

Comment: If you are asking a question, your code needs to be **Minimum Complete and Verifiable** according to StackOverflow rules. That means I should be able to take it and run it without commenting things in or out, without re-formatting it and without having to guess which bits are real and which bits a friend suggested... else it wastes everybody's time looking at unrepresentative stuff. Please try and make your question Minimal and Complete. Thank you.

Comment: I tried to change the Question, mostly the code and found a better code for sending signals. I hope that it is now better. I'm sorry for the issues that I made.